# Hide 4 in every 5 rows

Tags: excel, vba

Starting from row 10, which I need to keep unhidden, I need to hide the next 4 rows and repeat that pattern until the last row containing data

ie. keep row 10, 15, 20, 25 and so on, potentially up to around row 300

This is to fit in a larger VBA macro within Excel so i dont need an entire Sub () just the middle section.

I think I need to find lastrow
count rows from row 10 to last row
Select row 10
then skip row,
hide next 4 
loop... 
For loop assume but I don't really know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim lngLR As Long
lngLR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 10 To lngLR
    If i Mod 5 <> 0 Then ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next i
```

Comment: To explain a Bit more you can say that `i Mod 5 = 0` (Modulo) would be true only each time i is a multiple of 5

Comment: Note that you can jump to rows `10, 15, 20, 25 …` using `Step 5` in the loop and hide the next 4 rows *at once*, which should be much faster than hiding rows one-by-one. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58097011/3219613).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the following using `Step 5` in the `For` loop which should be faster than calculating the modulo for each `i`.  And then hide the following 4 rows at once instead of one-by-one.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet 'better define your sheet: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = 10 To LastRow Step 5 'means 10, 15, 20, 25 …
    ws.Rows(iRow + 1).Resize(RowSize:=4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next iRow
```

If you want to take better care of the last used row (don't hide any empty rows after `LastRow` use the following instead:

```
For iRow = 10 To LastRow - 1 Step 5 'means 10, 15, 20, 25 …
    If iRow + 5 > LastRow Then
        ws.Rows(iRow + 1).Resize(RowSize:=LastRow - iRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        ws.Rows(iRow + 1).Resize(RowSize:=4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next iRow
```

or even shorter (using `IIf`)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet 'better define your sheet: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Const NthRow As Long = 5 'show only every Nth row

Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = 10 To LastRow - 1 Step NthRow 'means 10, 15, 20, 25 …
    ws.Rows(iRow + 1).Resize(RowSize:=IIf(iRow + NthRow > LastRow, LastRow - iRow, NthRow - 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next iRow
```